# Is there a closed form for this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Given
$$
E_{n,k} = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n \leq k \\
n & \text{ if } k = 0 \\
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot E_{i,k-1} & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
$$
I wonder is there a closed form for this recurrence that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Where does this arise?  Just curiosity...

Comment: Seems to me like the calculation of an expected value involving two variables.  There is a recurrence $$E_{n+1, k} = \frac{1}{n+1} (n E_{n,k} + E_{n,k-1})$$ which suggests a probability of two sub-events happening.

Comment: Compare this to the identity $$C_{n+1, k} = C_{n,k} + C_{n, k-1}$$

Comment: $E_{n,k}$ has a generating function given by: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{n,k} z^{k-1} = \frac{n+1}{2-z} - \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{(z)_n}{n!(2-z)(1-z)}$$ where $(z)_n = z(z+1)\cdots(z+n-1)$ is the $n^{th}$ [Pochhammer polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol). No idea how to simplify this further.

Comment: @vonbrand: The problem is actually finding the expectation of $N$ given that $$\text{for } i = 1 \text{ to } k \{ N = \text{random}(N) \} \text{ where random }(N) = \{0, \ldots N-1\}$$ I tried to solved this problem using  Dynamic Programming in $O(N^3)$ but it was too slow, so I guess there must be a nicer form for computing this expectation.

Comment: But @Chan, if you're happy to write a programming solution, why don't you use the recurrence I mentioned above together with memoization?.  Better yet, construct the table for the new sequence given by: $$ D_{n+1,k} = D_{n,k} + \frac{1}{n} D_{n, k-1}$$ which is obtained by taking $D_{n, k} := n E_{n,k}$.  Constructing this table is simply an $O(nk)$ procedure and once you've calculated it once, you don't need to calculate it again.

Comment: @muzzlator: Thanks. Let me try that. But no matter what recurrence, I don't think it will pass the case when $N \leq 100,000, k \leq 100,000$ though. I've just realized, as $k$ gets larger, the result converges to 0 quite fast. I think I need to have a bound on both $k$ with respect to $n$.

Comment: @muzzlator: By the way, did you check your recurrence correctness? I don't think it produces the correct result though.

Comment: Chan, I remember it works when you set up the initial conditions properly.  ie) you need to have $n^2$ on the sides and do it manually for those.  Then you apply the operation.  Without this, you would get like $1$ and then $1,1$ rather than $1$ and $4, 1$.

Comment: @muzzlator: Would you mind elaborating how did you set up your initial values? The way I set it up was to initialize all $E_{n,1} = \dfrac{n-1}{2} \,\, \forall 1 \leq n \leq N$, but your recurrence only works for this case. I'm not sure what do you mean by "$n^2$ on the sides" though.

Comment: @achillehui, you should develop that into an answer.

Comment: Sorry @Chan, I had been busy the past few days.  Surprisingly, I saw what appears to be a duplicate of your own problem in the bounty section, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318857/sum-of-the-series-formula.  I think the more recent answer to this question discusses your formula nicely.

Comment: @muzzlator: No problem. Thanks for the link.